# JS/jQuery Cannot Update SVG Colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

### percent.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
    <defs>
        <script xlink:href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
        <linearGradient id="bg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#326384"/>
            <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#123752"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <pattern id="wave" width="100%" height="100%">
            <g id="waveWrap">

                <path id="wavePath" fill="url(#bg)" d="M-40 9 Q-30 7 -20 9 T0 9 T20 9 T40 9 T60 9 T80 9 T100 9 T120 9 V30 H-40z" mask="url(#mask)">
                    <animateTransform
                        // Options here...
                    />
                </path>
            </g>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <text class="pcnt" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="15" font-size="17" fill="url(#wave)"  fill-opacity="0.8">0%</text>
    <text class="loading" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="15" font-size="17" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.15">LOADING</text>
    <script>
        var ProgressColourTween = [
                "#ff4400", "#ff4900", "#ff4a00", "#ff4c00", "#ff4d00", "#ff4f00", "#ff5000", "#ff5100", "#ff5200", "#ff5400",
                "#ff5600", "#ff5700", "#ff5900", "#ff5a00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5e00", "#ff5f00", "#ff6100", "#ff6300",
                "#ff6400", "#ff6600", "#ff6700", "#ff6800", "#ff6900", "#ff6b00", "#ff6c00", "#ff6e00", "#ff6f00", "#ff7100",
                "#ff7200", "#ff7300", "#ff7500", "#ff7600", "#ff7800", "#ff7900", "#ff7a00", "#ff7c00", "#ff7d00", "#ff7f00",
                "#ff8700", "#ff8800", "#ff8a00", "#ff8b00", "#ff8c00", "#ff8e00", "#ff8f00", "#ff9100", "#ff9200", "#ff9400",
                "#ff9400", "#fc9500", "#fa9600", "#f79700", "#f59800", "#f29900", "#f09a00", "#ed9c00", "#eb9c00", "#e89e00",
                "#e69e00", "#e3a000", "#e0a100", "#dea200", "#dba300", "#d9a400", "#d6a500", "#d4a600", "#d1a700", "#cfa800",
                "#cca900", "#c9ab00", "#c7ab00", "#c4ad00", "#c2ae00", "#bfaf00", "#bdb000", "#bab100", "#b8b200", "#b5b300",
                "#b3b400", "#b0b500", "#adb600", "#abb700", "#a8b900", "#a6b900", "#a3bb00", "#a1bb00", "#9ebd00", "#9cbe00",
                "#99bf00", "#96c000", "#94c100", "#91c200", "#8fc300", "#8cc400", "#8ac500", "#87c600", "#85c700", "#82c800"
            ],
            s = Snap('svg'),
            waveWrap = s.select('#waveWrap'),
            percent=s.select(".pcnt"),
            loading=s.select(".loading");
        waveWrap.transform('t0,8');
        top.document.defaultView.setPercentage = setPercentage;
        function setPercentage(i){
            percent.attr({ text: i+"%"});
            waveWrap.transform('t0,'+(8-(i/8)));
            waveWrap.attr("fill",ProgressColourTween[ Math.ceil(i) ]);
        console.log(ProgressColourTween[ Math.ceil(i) ]);
            if (i===100) {
                // Do something
            }else{
                percent.attr("fill","url(#wave)")
                loading.attr({ text: "LOADING"});
            }
       }
    </script>
</svg>
```

### HTML

```
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        document.querySelector("object").addEventListener("load", function(event) {
           var setPercentage = this.getSVGDocument().defaultView.setPercentage,
               i=0;
            var interval=setInterval(function(){
                setPercentage(i);
                if (i>=100)
                    clearInterval(interval);
                i++;
            },100);
          });
      });
    </script>
    <object data="percent.svg"></object>
```

### The Problem

`console.log(ProgressColourTween[ Math.ceil(i) ]);` is showing a progressive log of all my colours in my `ProgressColourTween` array without no errors. There are 1090 colours in my array for each percentage level.

however when trying to modify the loading text colour with `waveWrap.attr("fill",ProgressColourTween[ Math.ceil(i) ]);` it is not doing anything. Everything is working in my code apart from the colour of the loading text updating.

### Question

How can I correctly update my SVG text colour from the colours in my array as the percentage changes?

Comment: I suggest you reduce your sample to something minimal so the least effort possible is required to follow what is going on.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I'm not entirely sure what the minimal is I'm sorry. I'm very new to SVG and so is my friend who helped to write this.

Comment: I meant cut down your example to the bare minimum required to demonstrate the problem. And perhaps put it in a plunkr or something so we can run it without having to do too much work.  For instance you could remove all the text field related stuff and the setInterval() loop. Also you could provide additional detail, like are you getting any console errors? Are the text fields updating? Is the loop working? Etc  Or is it an issue with the way you are tweening your colours?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have a live version [here](http://admin.bananza.org.uk/Loader.html) you can see this working as I'm not sure how to show all the source on one page due to obtaining `percent.svg` within an `<object></object>` but please note on my server it is `Loader.svg`. I will try and go through my question now to improve based on your feedback. Thank you

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have updated my question however I haven't removed much from my code as I still am not 100% sure what exactly is relevant to my question regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a colour to `<g id="waveWrap">` won't change the colour of the `<path>` that's inside it because that path already has a fill (`fill="url(#bg)"`) which overrides it.
If you want to change the colour of `#wavePath`, you will either have to change the `fill` on that element, or remove it so that the one on the group will apply.

```
wavePath.removeAttr('fill');
```

Comment: [Loader.html](http://admin.bananza.org.uk/Loader.html) > [Loader.svg](http://admin.bananza.org.uk/Assets/SVG/Loader.svg) I added `wavePath.removeAttr('fill');` to `line 50` however this does not seem to make a difference. Have I misunderstood your advice?

Comment: You don't appear to have defined and initialised the wavePath variable. It needs to point at the path element.

Comment: Ie. something like `wavePath = s.select('#wavePath')`

Comment: Sorry, line 50 within [Loader.svg](http://admin.bananza.org.uk/Assets/SVG/Loader.svg). I am new to SVG's, I just thought you meant to add `wavePath.removeAttr('fill');` from reading `remove it so that the one on the group will apply.` I should've looked in my console, it reads `wavePath.removeAttr is not a function`